# CPLEX Error 1016: Promotional version

Tags: cplex, opl

I have wrote a code for solving Integer Programming model in CPLEX oplide as follows:

```
nmbl = 521466;
nbi = 17;

int As[nbi] =...;

int amb[nmbl] = ...;
dvar boolean I[nmbl][nbi];

minimize 
sum (a in nmbl, b in nbi, c in nmbl: c>a,d in nbi: d != b) I[a][b]*I[c][d]*10;


subject to 
{
cons1:
forall (i in nmbl)
I[i][1] + I[i][2] + I[i][3] + I[i][4]+ I[i][5] + I[i][6] + I[i][7] + I[i][8] + I[i][9] + I[i][10] + I[i][11] + I[i][12] + I[i][13] + I[i][14] + I[i][15] + I[i][16] + I[i][17] == 1; 

cons2:
forall (j in nbi)
  sum (i in nmbl) I[i][j]*amb[i] <= As[j];
}
```

It shows an CPLEX Error  1016: Promotional version. Problem size limits exceeded. I will be thankful to you for providing me idea to locate the problem.

Comment: http://www.rpi.edu/dept/math/math-programming/cplex66/sun4x_56/doc/refman/html/appendixC.html

says about Error 1016 "The current problem size is too large for your version of CPLEX. Reduce problem size." 

It seems to be an issue with your version of the programm, not with the code itself, as the error message "Promotional Service" indicates.

Comment: Small doubt, I am new to research area, problem size is higher implies what?  :-- Size of the data used by me is much high (or) number of constraints produced by my code is high.

Comment: I think you will find that the limited version of CPLEX is typically limited to 1000 variables and 1000 constraints. Given the values nmbl = 521466 and nbi = 17, then the declaration dvar boolean I[nmbl][nbi]; is going to create almost 9 million boolean variables, which is *way* more than the limits I would expect on anything but the full version of CPLEX. In fact that is a really big binary problem that is likely to be very hard to solve.

Comment: Thank You PhillipD for your time... I will try to divide this IP formulation into sub problems.

Comment: Thank You TimChippingtonDerrick...

Comment: I am using academic version of CPLEX can other versions of CPLEX can handle 9 million variables.

Answer (score 0):

The current problem is too large for your version of CPLEX Free. Reduce the size of the problem. 
And you can to download this version :
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/CPLEX_Is_Free_For_Students?lang=en